# enable https on a GCE VM

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to install a certificate for all my subdomain on GCE VM, here is what I've done so far:

- Allow HTTPS traffic is enabled in the VM settings.
- I enabled the certificate on apache and default-ssl.conf looks like this

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
      ServerAdmin fadi@domain.com
      ServerName domain.com
      ServerAlias www.domain.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass /console https://0.0.0.0:8080/console
      ProxyPassReverse /console https://0.0.0.0:8080/console

      <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </FilesMatch>
      <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </Directory>
      BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                      nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                      downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
      BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

But still I can not reach my server on https but am still able to access it via http, even though I enabled ssl using

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Can someone help me please figure out this issue! the app is actually running on apache tomcat but proxied through apache if that make any difference!

Comment: got any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

443 is the default port used by Compute Engine for its services . Better you use any other port like 7443 or 8443 , then i guess it will work . I myself faced this issue on Compute Engine with Tomcat , and used other than the default ports . And also don't forget to mention whatever port you choose in the Firewall Rules section in the Networking . Let me know if that works !!